# Set imageview maximum size for android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.al.fullbodyxrayscanner.SaveImage" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/temp_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_overlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/body_xray"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/temp_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set `img_overlay` size(width and height) equal to the size of `temp_image`. `temp_image` is set from the bitmap created at run time.

Comment: if `temp_image` size not fix than you can try to set `img_overlay` programmatically as size of `temp_image`

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/body_xray"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/temp_image" />
```

when you set your image-view's width or height to `wrap_content` it will stretch as your image.